# Numerous 'No resource found' and 'Error retrieving parent' in Android Project

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Whilst trying to continue some work on my Android App, I came across numerous errors (which have been solved). However, I now receive around 100 errors all stating either

```
`error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'ATTR NAME'`.
```

**OR**

```
`error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'RESOURCE NAME'`.
```

(`ATTR NAME = attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark', attr 'android:colorAccent'` etc.
 `RESOURCE NAME='android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog','android:Theme.Material.Dialog'`etc.)

I'm almost positive this is a Project Build Target error even though the targets for `appcompat_v7` and my project is `API_LEVEL 21`. I have also removed any duplicated .jar files in the /lib folder as instructed to.

Any help is greatly appreciated as this problem has now consumed around 5-7 hours of my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your support library has been updated alongside with your api level, then try cleaning your project.

Make sure you are using updated support library.

Comment: I updated the Support Library's through the SDK Manager earlier to ensure they are up to date. How do I check this is in effect whilst on Eclispe?

Comment: There is a Project.properties file in which its written the build sdk, make sure it is 21 too!/

Comment: All that time and that was the problem. Thank you Aman for your help. One happy beginner right here now.